# Terraform: Deleted AWS keys before running Terraform Destroy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created some resources in AWS using TF these were used using the aws access and secret key. I accidentally deleted those keys not realising I needed to use TF destroy.

I have created new keys but I'm guessing TF requires the original keys.

I get this error

> Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

How do I get around this?

Comment: can you delete your `.terraform` directory and run `terraform init` again. After that you should be able to run `terrraform destroy`

Comment: I’ve deleted the directory and even created a new folder and copied the contents over. Same issue

Comment: In addition to what @OguzhanAygun said, after the terraform init cmd, type terraform providers lock - then try terraform destroy. Specifically try this: rm -rf ./.terraform & rm -rf .terraform.lock.hcl & terraform init && terraform providers lock

Comment: Can you post your `provider "aws" {}` block?

Comment: you can remove them from the state, `terraform state rm <resource>` after that, you will be able to create these keys again.